# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle, gradlew, gradle-plugin

I am trying to build the project but I am getting below error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: nexusUrl for class: org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject_Decorated
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ExtraPropertiesDynamicObjectAdapter.setProperty(ExtraPropertiesDynamicObjectAdapter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.setProperty(CompositeDynamicObject.java:122)
    at com.abc.gradle.plugins.nexus.staging.tasks.CreateStagingRepositoryTest.can set custom description(CreateStagingRepositoryTest.groovy:138)
```

I tried to add `nexusUrl` to *gradle.properties* file (as suggested by many) but it doesn't work too.

I want to know what does this error actually mean. Also, please suggest me workaround.

I am using *org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4*

Here's build.gradle:

```groovy
buildscript {
    dependencies {
       classpath "com.abc.gradle.plugins:abc-assert-plugin:1.0.1"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'abc-assert'
apply plugin:'groovy'
apply plugin:'idea'
apply plugin:'eclipse'

sourceCompatibility = targetCompatibility = "1.8"

nexusUrl = "http://nexus/nexus/content/groups/abc-artifacts"

//project.ext.set("nexusUsername", nexusUsername)

dependencies{
    compile gradleApi()
    compile localGroovy()
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.4'
    testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4'
}

jar {
  baseName=projectName
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: If possible, please post the relevant parts of your build.gradle file. Otherwise, there isn't enough information here.

Comment: Thanks fir your response Michael, I posted build.gradle file

Comment: `nexusUrl` would have to be available as a property on the `project`, but it is not. If you look at the `java` plugin, it adds a `convention` mapping so that you can simply set `sourceCompatibility` form the root of the build script. I'm guessing what people were suggesting were to add a `repositories { maven { url = 'http://nexus/nexus/content/groups/abc-artifacts' } }` block so that your dependencies can be resolved. What is making you add the `nexusUrl`?